# Passing Datagridview values to another form in VB.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to pass datagrid values to another form by clicking a table row My question is , if SELECT statement is the right code?

click table row > display results to other form

Edit : I got it working now

this is my new code:

```
Dim selectQ As String = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, MI, DOB, Age, Gender, Dept, DEP, MStatus, Phone1, Phone2, Tel, Email, HomeAdd, StreetAdd, CityAdd, Region, Refname1, Refname2, Refnum1, Refnum2 FROM Empinfo WHERE ID = " & Form4.MetroGrid1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString
```

Before:

```
Dim selectQ As String = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, MI, DOB, Age, 
                             Gender, Dept, DEP, MStatus 
                         FROM Empinfo 
                  WHERE ID = '" & Form4.MetroGrid1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Selected & "'"
```

'My full Code:

```
Private Sub Form6_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Dim constr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\DB1.accdb"
            Dim con As New OleDbConnection(constr)
            Dim datareader As OleDbDataReader
            Dim selectQ As String = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, MI, DOB, Age, Gender, Dept, DEP, MStatus FROM Empinfo WHERE ID = '" & Form4.MetroGrid1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Selected & "'"
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(selectQ, con)
            con.Open()
            datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader


            If datareader.HasRows Then
                datareader.Read()
                MetroTextBox1.Text = datareader(0).ToString
                MetroTextBox2.Text = datareader(1).ToString
                MetroTextBox3.Text = datareader(2).ToString
                MetroDateTime1.Text = datareader(3).ToString
                MetroComboBox1.Text = datareader(4).ToString
                MetroComboBox2.Text = datareader(5).ToString
                MetroComboBox3.Text = datareader(6).ToString
                MetroDateTime2.Text = datareader(7).ToString
                MetroComboBox5.Text = datareader(8).ToString

                datareader.Close()
            Else
                MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "There is no data present", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            End If
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            'MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, ex.ToString, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

i get data type mismatch when i run the program

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you want to pass the results of the query to the other form (title), OR do you want to run a query using a 'search' param from another form (the code)?  Either way, you should be using explicitly instanced forms and SQL parameters.

Comment: i'm passing the results to other form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's legal to call `Form4.MetroGrid1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Selected` it might not be accessing the instance of `Form4`, plus I don't think `.Selected` is the value you need for the statement. It would be better to make a `Sub New` for `Form6` that passes that data to it.

```
Public Class Form6
  Private id As String
  Public Sub New(id As String)
    Me.id = id
  End Sub

  Private Sub Form6_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        Dim constr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\DB1.accdb"
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection(constr)
        Dim datareader As OleDbDataReader
        Dim selectQ As String = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, MI, DOB, Age, Gender, Dept, DEP, MStatus FROM Empinfo WHERE ID = '" & id & "'"
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(selectQ, con)
        con.Open()
        datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        If datareader.HasRows Then
            datareader.Read()
            MetroTextBox1.Text = datareader(0).ToString
            MetroTextBox2.Text = datareader(1).ToString
            MetroTextBox3.Text = datareader(2).ToString
            MetroDateTime1.Text = datareader(3).ToString
            MetroComboBox1.Text = datareader(4).ToString
            MetroComboBox2.Text = datareader(5).ToString
            MetroComboBox3.Text = datareader(6).ToString
            MetroDateTime2.Text = datareader(7).ToString
            MetroComboBox5.Text = datareader(8).ToString
            datareader.Close()
        Else
            MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, "There is no data present", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End If
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        'MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(Me, ex.ToString, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try
  End Sub
End Class
```

Usage:

```
Dim f6 As New Form6(MetroGrid1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString)
f6.Show()
```

Comment: Did you check the value being passed?

Comment: i got it working now by myself , thanks anyway

i did this :

Dim selectQ As String = "SELECT FirstName, LastName, MI, DOB, Age, Gender, Dept, DEP, MStatus, Phone1, Phone2, Tel, Email, HomeAdd, StreetAdd, CityAdd, Region, Refname1, Refname2, Refnum1, Refnum2 FROM Empinfo WHERE ID = " & Form4.MetroGrid1.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString